# how to efficiently unzip large datasets in our local folder in google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, unzip

What is the fastest way to unzip folders with large datasets for model training?

```
 from zipfile import ZipFile

 # import training dataset
 output='/dataset'

 zf = ZipFile('/content/train_data.zip', 'r') # read input zip file
 zf.extractall(output) # extract to the output_dir in this case /content/sample_data
 zf.close()
```